# Не загружаются фото больше 1 мб PHP

Tags: php

При загрузке фото на сервер не добавляются изображения больше 1мб. В чем может быть проблема?

```html
$arr=array();

//ширина и высота в пикселях
$pic_weight = 15000;
$pic_height = 15000;

if ($_FILES)
{
  //пролистываем весь массив изображений по одному $_FILES['file']['name'] as $k=>$v
  foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $k=>$v)
  {
    //директория загрузки
    $uploaddir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/content/gallery/";
    //новое имя изображения
    $apend=date('YmdHis').rand(100,1000).'.png';
    //путь к новому изображению
    $uploadfile = "$uploaddir$apend";

    //Проверка расширений загружаемых изображений
    if($_FILES['file']['type'][$k] == "image/jpg" || $_FILES['file']['type'][$k] == "image/png" || $_FILES['file']['type'][$k] == "image/jpeg")
    {
      //черный список типов файлов
      $blacklist = array(".php", ".phtml", ".php3", ".php4");
      foreach ($blacklist as $item)
      {
        if(preg_match("/$item\$/i", $_FILES['file']['name'][$k]))
        {
          echo "Нельзя загружать скрипты.";
          exit;
        }
      }


      //перемещаем файл из временного хранилища
      if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$k], $uploadfile))
      {
        //получаем размеры файла
        $size = getimagesize($uploadfile);
        //проверяем размеры файла, если они нам подходят, то оставляем файл
        if ($size[0] < $pic_weight && $size[1] < $pic_height)
        {

          $arr[$apend] = "$apend";

          echo "<div class='green-result'>Файл ($apend) загружен.</div><br/>";
        }
        //если размеры файла нам не подходят, то удаляем файл unlink($uploadfile);
        else
        {
          echo "<div class='red-result'>Размер пикселей превышает допустимые нормы.</div><br/>";
          unlink($uploadfile);
        }
      }
      else
        echo "<div class='red-result'>Файл не загружен, вернитесь и попробуйте еще раз.</div><br/>";
    }
    else
      echo "<div class='red-result'>Можно загружать только изображения в форматах jpg, jpeg, gif и png.</div><br/>";
  }
  }
```

Comment: в настройках максимального размера загружаемого файла в php.ini

Comment: @teran В том и дело, что максимальный размер в php.ini - 50МБ. А тут картинка всего 1мб

Comment: Если у VPS то ограничения могут быть прописаны свыше, если на локалке - то отследите значение в ['error'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762467/php-file-upload-greater-than-upload-max-filesize-and-error). Аналогичные настройки еще есть в [.htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543194/strange-problem-while-uploading-large-files)

Answer (score 1):

Проверил на ошибки вот таким образом:

Ошибка была в ограничениях в самой форме:

```html
  <INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000">
```

```html
foreach ($_FILES['file']['error'] as $key => $error)
{
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
    {
        echo 'Ошибок не возникло, файл был успешно загружен на сервер';
    }
    else if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE)
    {
        echo 'Размер принятого файла превысил максимально допустимый размер, который задан директивой upload_max_filesize конфигурационного файла php.ini.';
    }
    else if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE)
    {
        echo 'Размер загружаемого файла превысил значение MAX_FILE_SIZE, указанное в HTML-форме.';
    }
    else if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL)
    {
        echo 'Загружаемый файл был получен только частично.';
    }
    else if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE)
    {
    echo 'Файл не был загружен.';
    }
    else if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR)
    {
        echo 'Отсутствует временная папка. Добавлено в PHP 5.0.3.';
    }
    else if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE)
    {
        echo 'Не удалось записать файл на диск. Добавлено в PHP 5.1.0.';
    }
    else if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION)
    {
        echo 'PHP-расширение остановило загрузку файла. PHP не предоставляет способа определить, какое расширение остановило загрузку файла; в этом может помочь просмотр списка загруженных расширений с помощью phpinfo(). Добавлено в PHP 5.2.0.';
    }
}
```